# UIButton that does something different the first time it is tapped

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have an UIButton that I want to bring up a UIAlertView the first time it is tapped (with instructions). What's the best way to do that? A toggle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd set an instance variable like `tappedFirstTime` to `YES` in `-(void)viewDidLoad` or wherever. And in your `IBAction` connected to your button, you can check for that variable and if `YES` you make it `NO`.